# Graph DFS slow running time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have an issue on running graph DFS for large amount data (n > 5,000,000). The problem is running time slowly. Could anyone points what I should change? I think time complexity of this is O(v * m). Thanks!

```
Graph.prototype.dfs = function(graph, vertex, cb) {


  // track which node visited
  var visited = {};

  // Take graph as option
  var list = graph ? graph : this.list;

  // get initial nodes
  var currentNodes = list[vertex];

  // Invoke given function for inital node
  cb(vertex);

  // Mark vertex as visited
  visited[vertex] = true;

  // If there is no node to traverse return 
  if (currentNodes.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  var stack = [...currentNodes];

  while (stack.length > 0) {

    // Get a node from stack
    var nextNode = stack.pop();
    if (!visited[nextNode]) {
      // Invoke given function
      cb(nextNode);
    }

    // Mark the vertex as visited
    visited[nextNode] = true;

    // Iterate adjacent nodes
    if (list[nextNode]) {
      for (var neighbor of list[nextNode]) {

        // If the vertex is not visited, push each nodes to stack
        if (!visited[neighbor]) { 
          stack.push(neighbor);
        }      
      } 
    } 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DFS complexity is O(V + M), so if its taking over 10s there is something wrong. The first thing I can see is that you are adding nodes to the stack without marking them as visited, so multiple nodes can end up adding same node to stack.

Try adding `visited[neighbor] = true;` after `stack.push(neighbor);`

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Now, stack does not have duplicate elements.

Comment: @sopian did the time improve?